# JAVAFX Show image on top of a rectangle

Tags: java, javafx

I'm developing a chess game using Java and JAVAFX.
My board is a JAVAFX group that contains an array of squares. My squares inherit from the JAVAFX rectangle class. I want to draw an image inside of these squares (image of the pieces) but I can't seem to find a way. when I use setfill to image Pattern the color of the square disappears which is not what I want I want the image to be transparent and drawn on top of each square. Any Ideas?

Comment: I think you may have answered your own question the sense that you want to draw the image "on top" of the squares; however, currently you are attempting to draw inside of the squares. The piece doesn't need to be part of the JavaFX Rectangle object, it just needs to be on top (z index/order).

Comment: Alternatively, use a `Pane` for the squares and place the `ImageView`s inside it.

Comment: https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/package-summary.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To place an image on top of a shape you can encapsulate both in a `StackPane`:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.image.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Chess extends Application {

    private final String[] COLORS = {"black","white"};
    private static int ROWS = 4, COLS = 4;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        Board board = new Board(COLS);

        int tileNum = 0;

        for(int row = 0; row < ROWS ; row++){
            tileNum = tileNum == 0 ? 1:0;
            for(int col = 0; col < COLS; col++){
                Tile tile = new Tile(COLORS[tileNum]);
                if(row==ROWS/2 && col == COLS/2) {//place an arbitrary piece
                    tile.setPiece(Pieces.KING.getImage());
                }
                board.addTile(tile.getTile());
                tileNum = tileNum == 0 ? 1:0;
            }
        }

        Parent root = new Group(board.getBoard());
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

class Board {

    private final TilePane board;

    public Board(int columns) {
        board = new TilePane(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
        board.setPrefColumns(columns);
        board.setTileAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        board.setStyle("-fx-border-color:red;");
    }

    Pane getBoard(){
        return board;
    }

    void addTile(Node node){
        board.getChildren().add(node);
    }
}

class Tile {

    public static final int SIZE = 100;
    private final StackPane tile;

    Tile(String colorName) {
        this(colorName, null);
    }

    Tile(String colorName, Image piece) {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(SIZE, SIZE, Color.valueOf(colorName));
        tile = new StackPane(rect);
        tile.setStyle("-fx-border-color:red;");
        if(piece != null) {
            setPiece(piece);
        }
    }

    void setPiece(Image piece){
        tile.getChildren().add(new ImageView(piece));
    }

    public Node getTile() {
        return tile;
    }
}

enum Pieces {

    KING ("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/softwaredemo/PNG/64x64/Circle_Blue.png"),
    QUEEN ("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/softwaredemo/PNG/64x64/Circle_Orange.png");

    private String image;
    private Pieces(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public Image getImage(){
        return new Image(image);
    }
}
```

It is quiet simple to change the representation of a tile to a `JavaFx` control such as `Label` or `Button`. All you need to do is some minor changes to `Tile`:

```
class Tile {

    public static final int SIZE = 100;
    private final Label tile;//a Button if you need it clickable

    Tile(String colorName) {
        this(colorName, null);
    }

    Tile(String colorName, Image piece) {
        tile = new Label();
        tile.setPrefSize(SIZE, SIZE);
        tile.setStyle("-fx-border-color:red; -fx-background-color:"+colorName);
        tile.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        if(piece != null) {
            setPiece(piece);
        }
    }

    void setPiece(Image piece){
        tile.setGraphic(new ImageView(piece));
    }

    public Node getTile() {
        return tile;
    }
}
```

---

[image]